# How to use this Ftp Code

Tags: c#, ftp

I am new c#. I want to know what I should change in this code to connect to my ftp server. Can anyone help me, please? I am unable to understand `string fileName`, `Uri serverUri`, `long offset`, So please help me.

```
ftphost address= localhost
username = test
password = test
filename = test.zip

   public static bool RestartDownloadFromServer(string fileName, Uri serverUri, long offset)
    {
        // The serverUri parameter should use the ftp:// scheme.
        // It identifies the server file that is to be downloaded
        // Example: ftp://contoso.com/someFile.txt.

        // The fileName parameter identifies the local file.
        //The serverUri parameter identifies the remote file.
        // The offset parameter specifies where in the server file to start reading data.

        if (serverUri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeFtp)
        {
            return false;
        }
        // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serverUri);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
        request.ContentOffset = offset;
        FtpWebResponse response = null;
        try
        {
            response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Status);
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            return false;
        }
        // Get the data stream from the response.
        Stream newFile = response.GetResponseStream();
        // Use a StreamReader to simplify reading the response data.
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(newFile);
        string newFileData = reader.ReadToEnd();
        // Append the response data to the local file
        // using a StreamWriter.
        StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText(fileName);
        writer.Write(newFileData);
        // Display the status description.

        // Cleanup.
        writer.Close();
        reader.Close();
        response.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Download restart - status: {0}", response.StatusDescription);
        return true;
    }
```

Thanks in Addvance.

Comment: Do you need to change it at all? And if yes, why?

Comment: If you want to learn c# - start from reading books and reviewing **simple** examples. If you need your work to be done - hire some one.

Comment: If you don't elaborate quickly, your question will be closed as "not a real question".  Please quickly expound on what you mean: in what sense do you not understand `string fileName` and the other parameters?

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen: at least streams and readers/writers need to be disposed correctly. I know you know that, but that is what could be changed there ;-)

Comment: Do you want to download a new file or not? fileName is the localfile Name, serverURIScheme is the combination of ftp server name and path to the file similar like a URL (you can actually test it in IE before using it in C#), offset is the number of bytes which were read in the previous ftp event.

Comment: But that shouldn't prevent the code from "working"...

Comment: Learning a language by blindly shooting questions to a website is a pretty slow (and spotty) way to learn. You would do better to find a good tutorial and follow along.

Answer (score 3):

The comments at the beginning of the method are more than adequate.

Call the method to kick things off:

```
 RestartDownloadFromServer("ftp://localhost/test.zip", "c:\test.zip", 0);
```

The example you have does not cope with username/password.  For that you will need to create a NetworkCredential and add it to the WebRequest.

Comment: Thank you sir, Can u plase tell me how to add a username and password .because i need   Secuity to downlaod the file.

Answer (score 2):

In your code sample are these words what else would you need.

**// The serverUri parameter should use the ftp:// scheme.
        // It identifies the server file that is to be downloaded
        // Example: ftp://contoso.com/someFile.txt.
        // The fileName parameter identifies the local file.
        //The serverUri parameter identifies the remote file.
        // The offset parameter specifies where in the server file to start reading data.**

Comment: `6,666` it is so sad to change such great reputation value with upvote ;-)

Comment: Yea :) Awww what a roller coaster

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're just beginning C#

Have a look at the following links. You need to learn to walk before you can run!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/beginner/bb308730.aspx

http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial.aspx